# Debian package installation for python3

Tags: cherrypy

As recommended by the Debian policy, it may exist a python3-cherrypy deb installer for CherryPy, but, obviously, it does not.

I am using *fpm* to build the packages of my application. This excellent tool extracts the dependencies from the setup.py of the application and uses the python prefix to manage the dependencies (*python-* and *python3-*). CherryPy is the only package I am using that is not complying to this policy ...

I searched in the CherryPy project documentations and I googled to find out if I miss something, but no success.

I suppose that I am not the only one that faced this situation and I am asking what is the best strategy. Re-package / rename CherryPy "standard" deb ? Build a specific deb for my application ?

Comment: If I were you I'd package two debs: one for cherrypy and other for your app. Also you may for advices at https://groups.google.com/group/cherrypy-users.

Comment: Ref: https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/issues/1711 (just for linking)